# SPAlert Timezone

Tags: alert

I am trying to set the time on a weekly user aler to Friday 6pm. And I do but..

We have users in many diffrenet timezones. How I do I know which timezone will trigger the 6pm alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based off the server time by default. It does not look at the time of that person, unless they change their regional settings in SharePoint.

[image]
[image]
[image]